# Java webservlet nothing gets to doPost

Tags: java, ajax

Whenever I do an AJAX POST to my Java webservlet, nothing seems to be happening. First I had problems posting from my other localhost port (I'm doing an AJAX post from `http://localhost:3000` to `http://localhost:8080`), but fixed that using a CORSFilter.

However, when I'm posting now, all seems to go well, but nothing happens in the POST itself.

This is the function:

```
module.exports = {
    postPerson: function (person) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/person',
                dataType: 'text',
                data: 'test',
                success: function(data){
                    console.log('success ' + data);
                },
                error: function(jQXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log("error");
                },
                failed: function(){
                    console.log('failed');
                },
                done: function() {
                    console.log('done');
                }
            })
        }
};
```

And the servlet:

```
package servlets;

import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/person")
public class PersonServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void init() throws ServletException {}

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
    {}

    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        System.out.println("testpost");
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        String student = request.getParameter("person");

    }
}
```

When looking in the browser console, it does print `success`, and in the XHR tab it tells me the POST is good, returning a 200. However, I expect 'testpost' to get printed, and I set a breakpoint at that point, but nothing happens.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Can you tell what is printed on browser console when 'console.log('success ' + data);' is run? Just success ???

Comment: @harshavmb it prints 'success' only

Comment: Where would the `println` go?  Do you have logging somewhere?`PersonServlet` doesn't do much and doesn't return anything.  What do you expect to happen?  Did you try setting a breakpoint on `doPost`?

Comment: @AndrewS That's just it, I am still in creation of it, thus I'd first need to know how data is posted to it. Yes, I did set a breakpoint and I have a printline there, but nothing happens.

Comment: you will never see anything if you don't properly write something in your response object. A simple response.getWriter().println("anything") would help.

Comment: @BigMike I see, well that is now the only thing I have in my doPost() function, but i'm not sure where to find this response back. I checked my browsers' XHR 'Response' tab, but it says only 'This request has no response data available'. It does return headers however, and a status 200.

Answer (score 0):

```
success : function(data) {
                    if(data!=null){
                        alert(data);
                        }else{
                            alert('Not working!!');
                        }
                    }
```

check data.

Comment: It does alert, it does have data, but the alert is empty it seems.

Comment: write something in response.

Comment: your are just set the type of response not the content. Please try to write response.getWriter().write("something");

Comment: I don't find the line I wrote back anywhere

Comment: It does say this on top of my logs: `Artifact project-name:war exploded: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.`, while it does seem to deploy

Comment: Have you deployed the war in tomcat? try to restart the tomcat server.

Comment: It later outputs this in the logs, so I do think so:
`Connected to server
[] Artifact project-name:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
[]Artifact project-name:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
[] Artifact project-name:war exploded: Deploy took 343 milliseconds`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest refreshing your war file on tomcat. Make sure to delete it and built your project again. Seems to me that it hasn't been updated, because if you are getting a 200 POST that means that you are getting to that doPost() method.

Comment: I did remove it and added it again. It seems to actually deploy, however this pops op on top of my logs when starting it:
`Artifact project-name:war exploded: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.`

Comment: Did you delete the exploded folder for your project too ?You need to delete both the project folder and the war file on tomcat. Then, re compile, deploy again. Regarding the message here are something you should consider to fix it. https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206837005--Server-is-not-connected-Deploy-is-not-available-in-tomcat